# Origin point spits clumps of particles

Tags: modifiers, particles

I was following this tutorial (https://youtu.be/SzbuZTlMGPE) and when I play the animation, clumps of particles in a line come out from the origin point, even though the boolean object isn't touching the origin point and the modifier stack option is enabled.[image]

Comment: Sam, you need to help the readers by clarifying your problem and question. Adding screenshots or illustration would also greatly increase your chance of getting an answer. thx!

Comment: Here is a video. Look closely at the center of the grid. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m65mBmWf8IbYkvQF-XQSaACGf-Dx9RBN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add the screenshots to your original question using the `Edit` button and again, please add details to your explanations as sometimes, people don't have time to watch lengthy videos.

Comment: Alright, I've added a screenshot.

Comment: can you show the particle settings used?

Comment: Here's the project file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/14rRrg-nwUwO-ZWXedcUOVZm4ze26ZWYB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to attach a blend file to your question. This way the link won't expire. Otherwise, I think this has to do with the progressive boolean operation  that may be sometimes creates weird geometry as the boolean intersection cube progresses right. I would try to keep the boolean but only do `difference` and use the generated faces as emitter. You may have to use `Dynamic Paint` modifier to select those faces.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=DxEx2eKz" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/DxEx2eKz/)

Comment: Please add this link to your question. It is better than in the comment.

Comment: It looks like the particles from the origin point are getting emitted when the boolean cube is exactly between letters (ex: between SAM and THE or between THE and MAN). It is like the particle system has no more faces to emit from do it defaults to the origin. May be try to separate all letters and use a particle system on each instead of on the full sentence.

Comment: ... or bake the particles and simply delete the unwanted ones...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106330/discussion-between-bruno-and-samtheman-6259).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The particle system is based on faces of the boolean intersection between a very narrow cube and the mesh text. The problem occurs when that boolean operation is between letters, creating an empty mesh. The particle system still needs to produce particles at the rate declared (10000 over a few dozen frames) and thus default to producing those particles somewhere at the Origin. May that's a bug... may be not.

Anyway, one workaround is to make the boolean cube (silver) wide enough to never create an empty mesh, i.e. as wide as the widest gap between your letters. This way the particle system will always some geometry to emit particles from instead of emitting from some random location.

Here you can see that with the narrow boolean, particles are emitted at the origin at frame 46 and later when it is in the gap:

[image]

And here the particles stopped being emitted at the origin when the boolean cube is wide enough to always intersect with the text object:

[image]